# How to achieve Löwdin transformation?

Tags: physical-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I use Gaussian 09 to obtain the Hamiltonian and overlap matrices, $H_0$ and $S_0,$ where the B3LYP functional and the 6-31G basis set are adopted. Then how to
transform the system to an orthogonal basis using Löwdin transformation?

$$
\begin{align}
H_1 &= S_0^{-\frac{1}{2}}H_0S_0^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
H &= U^\dagger H_1U
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Are you wondering how to perform Löwdin population analysis in Gaussian?

Comment: No, I just want to make an orthogonal transformation of the Hamiltonian matrix.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22124/unitary-transformation-of-the-hf-equations/22134#22134